# Can a memory address tell you anything about how/where the object is stored

Tags: pointers, memory, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-address

Is there a way you can identify whether an object is stored on the stack or heap solely from its memory address? I ask because it would be useful to know this when debugging and a memory address comes up in an error.

**For instance:**

If have a memory address: `0x7fd8507c6`
Can I determine anything about the object based on this address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention which OS you are using. I'll answer for Microsoft Windows as that's the one I've been using for the last 25 years. Most of what I knew about Unix/Linux I've forgotten.

If you just have the address and no other information - for 32 bit Windows you can tell if it's user space (lower 2GB) or kernel space (upper 2GB), but that's about it (assuming you don't have the /3GB boot option).

If you have the address and you can run some code you can use VirtualQuery() to get information about the address. If you get a non-zero return value you can use the data in the returned MEMORY_BUFFER_INFORMATION data.

The State, Type, and Protect values will tell you about the possible uses for the memory - whether it's memory mapped, a DLL (Type & MEM_IMAGE != 0), etc. You can't infer from this information if the memory is a thread's stack or if it's in a heap. You can however determine if the address is in memory that isn't heap or stack (memory in a DLL is not in a stack or heap, non-accessible memory isn't in a stack or a heap).

To determine where a thread stack is you could examine all pages in the application looking for a guard page at the end of a thread's stack. You can then infer the location of the stack space using the default stack size stored in the PE header (or if you can't do that, just use the default size of 1MB - few people change it) and the address you have (is it in the space you have inferred?).

To determine if the address is in a memory heap you'd need to enumerate the application heaps (GetProcessHeaps()) and then enumerate each heap (HeapWalk()) found checking the areas being managed by the heap. Not all Windows heaps can be enumerated.

To get any further than this you need to have tracked allocations/deallocations etc to each heap and have all that information stored for use.

You could also track when threads are created/destroyed/exit and calculate the thread addresses that way.

That's a broad brush answer informed by my experience creating a memory leak detection tool (which needs this information) and numerous other tools.